# How to change vbs code to send messages to all searched in Skype?

Tags: api, vbscript, skype

How to make following code send messages to all people who were found in Skype -> Search -> Dominating ??!?
I suppose that "For Each GAG In yADAl.Friends" should be changed to ""yaDal.Search("Dominating")"" but it doesn't work

```
on error resume next
set NrrlP = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set uDlVA = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
set yADAl = WScript.CreateObject("Skype4COM.Skype", "Skype_")
yADAl.Client.Start()
yADAl.Attach()
For Each GAG In yADAl.Friends
yADAl.SendMessage GAG.handle,"Type text here"
next
```

Comment: Hmm, please help me spam skype instant messaging - thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype does not provide functionality which can lead to spamming its abonates. This what you want to do may be considered as unlawful.